# Negative lookbehind. How to fix regex to use it in IE11, Safary?

Tags: javascript, regex, safari, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying to create regexp matching `<<merge_field>>` and not matching `href="<<merge_field>>`

I've used negative lookbehind construct, but it doesn't work in IE11 and Safari. Is there any regexp solution?

Current expression is `(?<!href=")[<]{2}((?:merge_field))[>]{2}`

Comment: There is _**NO JS ALTERNATIVE FOR LOOK BEHIND ASSERTIONS**_ Please understand that !!!! The only way to match something _bad_ is to move the match position past it. This requires matching the bad part as well as the good.

Comment: You can match both `(href=['"]<<merge_field>>)|(<<merge_field>>)` used in a replace callback. Return group 1 with itself. Return group 2 with the replacement, or with itself if just recording the position.

Comment: I've tried to do this way, but it replaces both $1 and $2. Did I do something wrong?  const regexMergeFields = new RegExp('(href=\"<<' + mergeFields+ '>>)|<<(' + mergeFields+ ')>>', 'g');  return str.replace(
      regexMergeFields,
      this.wrapMergeField('$2')
    );

Comment: Added an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a single regex, we match the part that would normally be skipped with a lookbehind asserrtion`href="<<merge_field>>`
and also the part that you need `<<merge_field>>`.

This is the *ONLY* way to work around the lookbehind deficit in JS.
This works by completely consuming the bad part, and moves the current position past it
There is *NO* other way, don't be fooled.

This is done within a string replace callback.
Within the callback you can do the logic to control what get's written back as part of the replacement.

In our callback, if group 1 is matched, we just return group 1 thus not changing it's content.

If group 2 is matched, you can decide whether to just return group 2 changing nothing
(if you're just recording its position or pushing an array element),
or just change it to what you want.

```js
var target = "href=\"<<merge_field>> and <<merge_field>> and href=\"<<merge_field>>";

var targ_new = 
    target.replace( /(href=["']<<merge_field>>)|(<<merge_field>>)/g,
       function( match, grp1, grp2 ) {
          if ( grp1 )
             return grp1;
          return "MRG"; // or return grp2 if just recording location
       }
    );

console.log( "Before:\r\n" + target);
console.log( "After:\r\n" + targ_new );
```